# Pure HTML Loggin front route to Vaadin apps

Tags: html, authentication, vaadin

How to join pure HTML file as Front page to login and go through Vaadin7.5 Apps (label as contentMode.html doesn't give success).

I've seen esigate can merge but sound only JSP file.

Comment: Who is doing the login validation?

Comment: I will use HTML Front  to present the application and include vaadin forms to register.

Comment: So what prevents you to have some html forms on a html page? Just make sure the .html file is not handled by the servlet engine